# Method in Mocked object is not called from sut

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I make MSTests for my card game. I have Player class (it depends on `IStrategy` interface) which has a method `Attack()` that calls `interface.Attack()` method. `Mock<IStrategy>` is created and set up `strategy.Attack()`. But when `Player.Attack` is called, `mock.Attack` is not call.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
    public class Player : IPlayer
    {
        public List<Card> CardsOnHands { get; }
        public IStrategy Strategy { get; }

        public Player(IStrategy strategy)
        {
            Strategy = strategy;
            CardsOnHands = new List<Card>();
        }

        public Card Attack(List<Card> CardsOnTable)
        {
           return Strategy.Attack(CardsOnHands, CardsOnTable);
        }
    }
```

My test follows

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void PlayerAttackShouldReturnCard()
    {
        //Arrange
        var StrategyMock = new Mock<IStrategy>();
        ExpectedCard = new Card(1, "fakeName", "fakeSuit", true);
        CardList = new List<Card>
        {
        new Card(1, "", "", true),
        new Card(1, "", "", true),
        new Card(1, "", "", true)
        };

        StrategyMock
            .Setup(x => x.Attack(CardList, CardList))
            .Returns(ExpectedCard);
        var _player = new Player (StrategyMock.Object);
        //Act
        Card actualCard = _player.Attack(CardList);
        //Assert
        StrategyMock.Verify(x => x.Attack(CardList, CardList), Times.Exactly(1));
        Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedCard, actualCard);
    }
```

`Verify` fails

Comment: The real problem was that I used same List<Card> (x.Attack(CardList, CardList) instead of It.IsAny<List<Card>>(). Replacement fixed the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly inject the mocked interface into the subject class (`_player`).

The current example does not show where you do that.

It would need to look something like

```
[TestMethod]
public void PlayerAttackShouldReturnCard() {
    //Arrange
    var strategyMock = new Mock<IStrategy>();
    var expectedCard = new Card(1, "fakeName", "fakeSuit", true);
    var tableCards = new List<Card> {
        new Card(1, "", "", true),
        new Card(1, "", "", true),
        new Card(1, "", "", true)
    };

    strategyMock
        .Setup(x => x.Attack(It.IsAny<List<Card>>(), tableCards))
        .Returns(expectedCard)
        .Verifiable();

    Player _player = new Player(strategyMock.Object); //<--- explicit injection here

    //Act
    Card actualCard = _player.Attack(TableCards);

    //Assert
    strategyMock.Verify();
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCard, actualCard);
}
```